# Can speed be entangled?

Tags: conservation-laws, quantum-entanglement

When reading about [quantum entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement), I see that all variables that are discussed (spin for instance) have discrete states.

Can a continuous variable such as speed be entangled? In the case of annihilation for instance with two particles moving at a certain speed - by measuring the speed of one of them one knows what the other speed is.

In that case, though, I wonder how different this is from the laws of conservation.

Comment: "In that case, though, I wonder how different this is from the laws of conservation." That's a good point. You would think that you know the momentum of the other particle by measuring one of them, regardless of entanglement. I guess there is a bunch of values collapsing to two opposites. All opposite combinations are entangeled.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, speed can - and almost always is, if you pick a random particle in the universe - entangled. As are most variables. The corresponding operator for speed is just the magnitude of total momentum operator divided by mass. Positions can be entangled, momenta can be entangled... all it takes for a state to be entangled is that the wave function in (for instance) momentum space cannot be factored into separate products of individual momenta:

$$\psi(p_1, p_2, ... p_n) \neq \psi(p_1) \psi(p_2) ...\psi(p_n)$$

Generally, except in special cases, there is no reason why the state should be of the form above.

Comment: Can the positions of two separated particles be entangled? Or only if the wavefunctions overlap?

Comment: Particles can be entangled in position even at distant locations. Take for example the stern gerlach experiment, done on two particles in the singlet state. These particles also have a position wave function, and they will always go in opposite directions - this is in fact how we infer what their spin is to begin with.

Comment: Ah yes. So before the measurement both particles are up as well as down and the measurement on one fixes the other?

Comment: Yep, that's right!